# How to convert this date into actual date

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date

So this is a new one to me.  I've been working with this api and they returned a date in json format that looks like this

```
{
 DateAdd: "/Date(1582936941390-0600)/"
}
```

not exactly sure how to convert this to a datetime like in the format below so I can actually do something with it.

```
2020-03-13 23:08:00
```

i have never seen this date format before!  Thanks

Comment: It's probably some sort of epoch time format e.g. number of seconds from 1970 or something. Recommend importing momentjs into your project and using that to make your life easier.

Comment: Just FYI, moment.js is a 329 kb library.

Comment: Does the API have documentation concerning its date/timestamp formats?

Comment: No it doesnt provided any documentation.  But I will look into moment JS seems like everyone is using this

Comment: You could potentially use moment.js to figure out what the format is. Maybe it has some kind of format identification features. Once you figure out what the format is, you could write your own function to parse it. But if you're using this on the frontend, you absolutely shouldn't use moment.js; it's gigantic. [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) is a great alternative. Though I don't know definitively if it would handle this format.

Comment: Sounds good dude thanks for all the support , most definitely opened me up to a new library that I can tell I will enjoy :)

Comment: FYI - This was the format that ASP.Net used to use when serialising `DateTime`s

Comment: See [* How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use moment.js to convert the date format

```js
var data = {
 DateAdd: "/Date(1582936941390-0600)/"
}
var datam = moment(data.DateAdd)
console.log(datam.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")) // 2020-02-29 07:42:21
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just FYI, moment.js is a 329 kb library.

Comment: So Krisitan thanks for answering! Seems simple dude. Thanks @Cully I was just going to ask should I use a whole library for this 1 thing ? Quite small

Comment: Note that moment.js **ignores** the timezone offset. This is equivalent to [Robo Robok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60629268/257182) with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the timezone, you can just cut the timestamp out of that string:

```js
const dateString = data.DateAdd;
const date = new Date(Number(dateString.match(/\d+/)[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I actually needed the timezone. was trying to avoid stripping it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date into desired format by **Javascript date** object.

```js
let addZero = (i) => {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }
    
let formatDate = (date) => {
        let year = date.getFullYear(),
            month = addZero(date.getMonth() + 1),
            day = addZero(date.getDate() + 1),
            hours = addZero(date.getHours() + 1),
            minutes = addZero(date.getMinutes() + 1),
            seconds = addZero(date.getSeconds() + 1);
        let dateArr = [year, month, day];
        let timeArr = [hours, minutes, seconds];
        let result = dateArr.join('-').concat(" ", timeArr.join(':'));
        return result;
    }
    
let inputString = "/Date(1582936941390-0600)/";
let inputData = new Date(Number(inputString.match(/\d+/)[0]));

console.log(formatDate(inputData));
```

Please read more about [Javascript date object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)